# How can I evaluate an expression in IDA Pro?

Tags: ida

I want to evaluate an expression on IDA Pro.  Look at this code:

```
mov rex, [rbp + var_XYZ]
```

If I put my cursor on `[rbp + var_XYZ]`, it will show me the value of the address and content, but I would like to see individually `rbp` value and `var_XYZ`.

I also want to change values of `var_XYZ`. I have tried a lot of things.

Thanks

Comment: `var_XYZ` only describes an offset to a position within the stack frame. At the top of your function you should see definitions like `var_50= qword ptr -50h`. That means every time you see `var_50` you can substitute it with `-50h` and the expression is the same.  That is, `[ebp+var_50]` would mean `[ebp-50h]`.

Comment: So with that in mind, what do you intend to do? Do you want to alter an instruction to access a different location (e.g. `[ebp-40h]` instead of `[ebp-50h]`)?  Or do you want to change the contents of memory at such a location?